# Python Apache Beam Google Storage Write error

Tags: python, mongodb, google-cloud-storage, pymongo, apache-beam

I am trying to write my pipeline response to Google Storage but getting module import error which is already installed on the server.

## Code:

```
from __future__ import print_function, absolute_import
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
from apache_beam.transforms import PTransform, ParDo, DoFn, Create
from apache_beam.io import iobase, range_trackers
import logging
import re
import argparse
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

def mongo_connection_string(url):
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
if 'gs://' in url:
    from google.cloud import storage
    logging.info('Fetching connection string from Cloud Storage {}'.format(url))
    _, path = url.split('gs://')
    path = path.split('/')
    bucket = path[0]
    path = '/'.join(path[1:])
    client = storage.Client()
    blob = client.get_bucket(bucket).get_blob(path).download_as_string()
    connection_string = blob.splitlines()[0]
    return connection_string
logger.info('Using connection string from CLI options')
return url

iso_match = re.compile(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}')

def clean_query(query):
    new_query = {}
    for key, val in query.iteritems():
        if isinstance(val, basestring):
            val = str(val)
    if isinstance(val, basestring) and iso_match.match(val):
        val = datetime.datetime.strptime(val[0:19], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    elif isinstance(val, dict):
        val = clean_query(val)
    new_query[str(key)] = val
return new_query

class _MongoSource(iobase.BoundedSource):
   import pymongo
   def __init__(self, connection_string, db, collection, query=None, fields=None):
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    self._connection_string = connection_string
    self._db = db
    self._collection = collection
    self._fields = fields
    self._client = None

    # Prepare query
    self._query = query
    if not self._query:
        self._query = {}
    logger.info('Raw query: {}'.format(query))
    self._query = clean_query(self._query)
    logger.info('Cleaned query: {}'.format(self._query))

@property
def client(self):
    import logging
    import pymongo
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    if self._client:
        logger.info('Reusing existing PyMongo client')
        return self._client
    logger.info('Preparing new PyMongo client')
    self._client = pymongo.MongoClient(self._connection_string)
    return self._client

def estimate_size(self):
    return self.client[self._db][self._collection].count(self._query)

def get_range_tracker(self, start_position, stop_position):
    from apache_beam.io import iobase, range_trackers
    if start_position is None:
        start_position = 0
    if stop_position is None:
        stop_position = range_trackers.OffsetRangeTracker.OFFSET_INFINITY
    range_tracker = range_trackers.OffsetRangeTracker(start_position, stop_position)
    range_tracker = range_trackers.UnsplittableRangeTracker(range_tracker)

    return range_tracker

def read(self, range_tracker):
    coll = self.client[self._db][self._collection]
    for doc in coll.find(self._query, projection=self._fields):
        yield doc

def split(self, desired_bundle_size, start_position=None, stop_position=None):
    from apache_beam.io import iobase, range_trackers
    if start_position is None:
        start_position = 0
    if stop_position is None:
        stop_position = range_trackers.OffsetRangeTracker.OFFSET_INFINITY
    yield iobase.SourceBundle(
        weight=1,
        source=self,
        start_position=start_position,
        stop_position=stop_position)


class ReadFromMongo(PTransform):
    def __init__(self, connection_string, db, collection, query=None, fields=None):
        super(ReadFromMongo, self).__init__()
        self._connection_string = connection_string
        self._db = db
        self._collection = collection
        self._query = query
        self._fields = fields
        self._source = _MongoSource(
        self._connection_string,
        self._db,
        self._collection,
        query=self._query,
        fields=self._fields)

def expand(self, pcoll):
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info('Starting MongoDB read from {}.{} with query {}'
                .format(self._db, self._collection, self._query))
    return pcoll | iobase.Read(self._source)

def display_data(self):
    return {'source_dd': self._source}


def transform_doc(document):
    data={str(document['clause type']):int(document['count'])}
    return data
def run():
    import time
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--output',
                  dest='output',
                  default='<output path>',
                  help='Output file to write results to.')
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args()
    gcs_path = "<gcs URL>"
    project_name = "<project name>"
    pipeline_args.extend(['--runner=DataflowRunner', 
    "--project=civic-eye-181513",
    "--staging_location=<stagging location>",
    "--temp_location=<temp location>"
    ])
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
    print ("starting pipleline")
    connection_string = '<mongo URL>'
    (pipeline
     | "Load" >> ReadFromMongo(connection_string, 'new', 'Data', query={}, fields=['clause type','count'])
     | "transform" >> beam.Map(transform_doc).with_output_types(str)
     | "Save" >> WriteToText("{0}/output/wordcount{1}".format(gcs_path,int(time.time()))))
print ("done")     

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

## Error:

```
Exception in worker loop: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File  "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 738, in run work,
  execution_context, env=self.environment)
 File  "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/workitem.py",  line 130, in get_work_items
  work_item_proto.sourceOperationTask.split)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/workercustomsources.py", line 142, in  __init__
  source_spec[names.SERIALIZED_SOURCE_KEY]['value'])
 File  "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 225, in loads return 
  dill.loads(s)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 277, in loads
  return load(file)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 266, in load
  obj = pik.load()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
  dispatch[key](self)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1133, in load_reduce
  value = func(*args)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 766, in _import_module
  return __import__(import_name)
ImportError: No module named pymongo
```

## Note: Pymongo module is already installed with newest version:

```
pip show pymongo    
Name: pymongo    
Version: 3.5.1    
Summary: Python driver for MongoDB <http://www.mongodb.org>    
Home-page: http://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver    
Author: Bernie Hackett    
Author-email: bernie@mongodb.com    
License: Apache License, Version 2.0    
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you are using some non default python libraries, like your own utils library or some dependencies from pypi, then you need to provide either a `requirements` or a `setup` file. You can see the details about it at [this link](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dependencies-python)

The reason for this is, that when you submit a job to dataflow, your code is actually run on different compute engines that dataflow service spins up for you. All the dependencies that you are using need to be installed on them. This can be achieved by providing the `requirements` or a `setup` file.

Since you are using a pypi dependency, all you need to do is

1. Create a requirements file by executing `pip freeze>requirements.txt`
2. provide that requirements file to the pipeline options

To provide the requirements file, provide the parameters using the following code

```
requirements_file = "/path/to/requirements_file"
pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).requirements_file = requirements_file
```

So your run functions should look as follows

```
def run():
    import time
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--output',
                  dest='output',
                  default='<output path>',
                  help='Output file to write results to.')
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args()
    gcs_path = "<gcs URL>"
    project_name = "<project name>"
    pipeline_args.extend(['--runner=DataflowRunner', 
    "--project=civic-eye-181513",
    "--staging_location=<stagging location>",
    "--temp_location=<temp location>"
    ])
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
requirements_file = "/path/to/requirements_file"
pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).requirements_file = requirements_file
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
    print ("starting pipleline")
    connection_string = '<mongo URL>'
    (pipeline
     | "Load" >> ReadFromMongo(connection_string, 'new', 'Data', query={}, fields=['clause type','count'])
     | "transform" >> beam.Map(transform_doc).with_output_types(str)
     | "Save" >> WriteToText(" {0}/output/wordcount{1}".format(gcs_path,int(time.time()))))
print ("done")
```

---

If you were needed to use some custom written python packages, like your own utils file, then all you need to do is, create the setup file using `setuptools` and provide it in similar way as `requirements` file.

You could read about `setuptools` at [this link](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Now getting this error:                                                                                                           The Dataflow appears to be stuck. Please reach out to the Dataflow team at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-dataflow.

Comment: What's the version you are using of Apache beam?

Comment: Apache-beam 2.1.0 has a known issue that it installs package `six` version 1.11 which isn't compatible with it. You will need to downgrade package to version 1.10. Apparently apache-beam 2.1.1 takes care of it.

Comment: I am using 2.1.1 version

Comment: Check out `worker-startup` logs on Google Cloud Logging for the specific data flow job

Comment: No matching distribution found for PAM==0.4.2 , But when I tried to install this package was giving error. Can I install different version of PAM?

Comment: Yes, obviously. First make sure that works locally. It will save you time.

Comment: Dont forget to update the version in requirements file

Comment: I installed PAM==0.1.4 and updated in requirements.txt but dataflow is still looking for PAM==0.4.2 which is not available so Job is getting stuck. :(

Comment: Did you update the version in requirements file? That's the catch The data flow service will look at your requirements file and install it from there. If you don't mention that in the requirements file, it will obviously will look for latest version

Comment: Yes , I updated at my local system plus on the job worker's VM machine. Now its giving dependency for Ubuntu package so how can we install Linux package via requirements.txt . As the VM is Customized OS we cant install or update package manually.

Comment: You're not supposed to install packages manually on VM instance, execute `pip freeze>requirements.txt` this will update your requirements file. And pass that file to the pipeline options. It should do the trick.

Comment: Plus I have deleted few packages from requirements file as there is no such package /version available. (e.g: command-not-found==0.3,adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4,xdiagnose===3.6.3build2). Will this effect the process?

Comment: Create a clean virtual environment, then try running your job on local runner. Once it starts running properly on local runner, you can't create the requirements file using the `pip freeze`. Pass this to the pipeline options and execute the job on dataflow runner.

Comment: It worked like a charm..Thanks a lot for your help and guidance...Do you have any idea about how to write Apache_beam output to MongoDB?

Comment: Maybe you could create a REST api to write the data to your mongodb.
The reason of creating an api is, because the dataflow jobs run on compute engines of GCP.

Comment: I have created a REST API but don't know how to call within runner. like which write function will have to call and how to call my own defined API?

Comment: I am no apache beam expert, but i think you can use python requests module to make those calls

Comment: Dont forget to mark this as the right answer if it helped you!